# How to get the applications of the resourcegroup the Azure workbook is in?

Tags: azure, azure-monitor-workbooks

I have a resource group with some functions apps and an Azure Monitor Workbook.
In this workbook I want to list all apps.
How to do this? I only managed to get all apps in the subscription, which is too much.

First I created a Parameter to get the correct resource group:

```
resourcecontainers
| where type =~ "microsoft.resources/subscriptions/resourcegroups"
| where name startswith "foo"
| project name
```

And then a Parameter with the applications:

```
resources
| where type == "microsoft.web/sites"
| where resourceGroup == "{ResourceGroup}"
```

This is working, but I want to get rid of the hardcoded part in the ResourceGroup Parameter: `foo`

I'm looking for something like this:

```
resources
| where type == "microsoft.web/sites"
| where resourceGroup == "{_CurrentResourceGroup}"
```

Answer (score 0):

there's no "built-in" parameters like that.  is the workbook saved "linked"  to a specific resource or is it saved to a place like "Azure Monitor" that isn't a full resource.

if it is saved linked to a real resource, you can get that "owning" resource as a parameter by creating a resource parameter with the "owning resource" option:
[image: owning resource parameter]

That parameter would always be the value of the resource that the workbook is linked to. you could then use to get the resource group/resource info. like `{linkedToResource:resourceGroup}` or `{linkedToResource:subscriptionId}` or whatever?

#### why is this not available as a thing in a workbook?

because the workbook might not be *saved* (it could be temporary thing you just started and never saved, it could be a template, etc) and until it is *saved* the workbook itself doesn't have a resource id, so it doesn't belong to a resource group.

Comment: Thanks John, I tried that but the 'Owner Resource' is the subscription which is not in a resource group, the resource group is in this subscription: `{LinkedToResource:resourcegroup} ==> undefined`   
I saved the workbook in the resource group which also contains the FunctionApp and other resources related to this application. So it should have a resoource ID, but how to get it?

Comment: if the owning resource is a *subscription*, then yes, it wouldn't also have a RG set.  if the workbook is saved to the same place as the function app, you could have a parameter that selects/queries ARG for the function apps, and use that selected resource id?  Or you could add a subscription parameter, and then a resource group parameter that queries the resource groups that have function apps from ARG and use that for further filtering?

Comment: Thanks John for helping, I really appreciate it. Our subscription has multiple rgs and those rgs have function apps. So when I query for the function apps in the subscription I get all the function apps in all the resource groups. I could filter by function app name, but then I'm in the same situation when getting the rg filtered by name.